# Error when trying to use custon UITableViewCell "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key..."

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have seen the other questions about cleaning up the connections in the nibs, but I don't believe that is my problem.

Currently I'm importing a custom UITableViewCell class, registering the nib in the VC with the UITableView in that VC's viewDidLoad as follows:

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
UINib* cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"[nib for the custom cell]" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[_theTableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

Then later in the VC I implement the method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"cell";
  CustomTableCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:outgoingNoteIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

  return cell;
}
```

If I don't connect any of the properties in the custom cell (just labels and buttons), then it loads fine, and I can see the images associated with both the labels and the buttons. When I try to connect just one of the properties in the xib file though, I get the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds like you are connecting your Nib outlets to the `file's owner`. 
Try connection them directly to the `cell` instead.

I usually follow this flow:

1. Set `file's owner` to your custom cell class
2. Add outlets to file's owner, to get generated properties
3. Set `cell's` Custom Class to be same as the one specified as `file's owner`
4. Add all outlets to the `cell`. XCode will now show the properties your created in step 2

Happy coding

Comment: thanks, it seems like this is the problem. if you get a chance could you point me in the direction of an explanation why this is the case. is file's owner only used for view controllers?

Comment: It depends on how the nib is loaded. If your custom class has a view property you expect to point at a view, loaded from a xib, you need to use the owner pattern. If you class is a view, you need to set the outlet directly on the view.