# Can't connect outlets created with code to the static cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying the static cell part of this tutorial

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702

But I can't get it to work. I think the outlets that I created are not connected to the cells, but I can't see how to do that, I've attached a screen shot of my XCode screen which will hopefully make it clearer what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: Make sure that you've set the custom class in IB to `HelloWorldViewController` then control+drag from the labels to the `IBOutlet`s. If this doesn't work then also check that the `Table View->Content` is set to `Static Cells`.

Answer (score 2):

Static cells are supposed to be configured in the Storyboard and in it alone. It is WYSIWYG (What You See Is What You Get) approach, and for that reason you *cannot* create an outlet from a static cell. Change the type to Dynamic Prototypes and try again.

Comment: It's hard to see clearly, but I thought I saw `UILabel` outlet? How about not dragging _into_ existing outlet, but creating a new one by dragging into an empty space between `@interface` and `@end`.

Comment: @Phil Might I recommend: https://itunes.apple.com/il/course/1.-class-logistics-overview/id733644550?i=169514574&mt=2

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Your outlets are not connected correctly. See the non-filled circles in the Breakpoint area of your code view, next to your outlet properties? If connections were setup correctly those circles would be filled.

You need to click and hold on the non-filled circle.

You then move your mouse to the `UIView` you want to connect it to. XCode will draw a line from the circle to the `UIView` while you drag. When the connection is established, the circle indicater turns solid

See also this answer [Error when trying to use custon UITableViewCell "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24435131/error-when-trying-to-use-custon-uitableviewcell-this-class-is-not-key-value-cod/24435251#24435251).

Comment: Have you tried following the steps in the answer I link to?

Comment: I don't get steps 3/4.

Answer (score 0):

You can't wire it up directly from storyboard to custom cell class, but you can do this in your init code in the cell:

```
customCellClassLabel = self.viewWithTag(100) as! UILabel
```

In your static cells, use a tag number to the labels